# Pandas: correctly resampling data at the hourly frequency

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In Python 3.6.3, I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
                 dt     Val
2017-04-10 08:00:00     8.0
2017-04-10 09:00:00     2.0
2017-04-10 10:00:00     7.0
2017-04-11 08:00:00     3.0
2017-04-11 09:00:00     0.0
2017-04-11 10:00:00     5.0
2017-11-26 08:00:00     8.0
2017-11-26 09:00:00     1.0
2017-11-26 10:00:00     2.0
```

I am trying to compute the hourly average of these values, so as to have:

```
    Hour     Val
08:00:00     7.00
09:00:00     1.00
10:00:00     4.66
```

My attempt:

```
df2 = df1.resample('H')['Val'].mean()
```

Returns the same dataset as `df1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: df.groupby(df['dt'].dt.hour).Val.mean()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the comments above, I tested that the following works for me:

```
df.groupby(df.index.hour).Val.mean()
```

Or you can make the index values `'timedelta'` dtypes

```
df.Val.groupby(df.index.hour.astype('timedelta64[h]')).mean()

dt
08:00:00    6.333333
09:00:00    1.000000
10:00:00    4.666667
Name: Val, dtype: float64
```